# Javascript: Are variables in prototype functions shared across objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var Socket = (function() {

    var Socket = function(ioSocket) {
        this._ioSocket = ioSocket;
    };

    Socket.prototype = {

        release: function() {
            var some = 0;

            this._ioSocket.on('ack', function() {
                some = some + 1;
                console.log(some);
            });
        }
    return Socket;
}());
```

The `_ioSocket.on` part just represents any async callback. If I do:

```
new Socket(ioSocket).release()
```

multiple times, is it then guaranteed that the console will always print 1 given that the `on('ack')` callbacks can fire in random order? Or is it possible that something else is printed since all Sockets point to the same `some` variable?

Comment: What if you try first?

Comment: Although this is not a bad idea at all I assume that I might run into false positive with this one.

Comment: `some` will either be `0` (if the release function is not called) or `1` if it was called (and will be logged). This happens because `some` is set to 0 every time the `release` function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as each call to release only results in one invocation of the `.on` callback then `.release()` will always print 1, since each new call to `release` creates a new copy of the variable `some`.

Comment: What do you mean by once? Once on total? Once per release() call?

Comment: @user2820379 Yes, once per `release()` call. `some` is just a local variable in a function, and a new copy of `some` will be created every time `release` is called.